# Touchable image as annotation callout?

Tags: objective-c, mkannotation, mapkit

I tried to use BarButton but this is wrong:

```
CGSize thumbSize = CGSizeMake(30.0, 30.0);
UIImageView *annotationThumbnail = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[((Sight *)annotation).thumbnail imageToFitSize:thumbSize method:MGImageResizeScale]];
UIBarButtonItem *annotationButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:annotationThumbnail];

annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = annotationButton;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIBarButtonItem` is not a subclass of UIView, so using an instance of `UIBarButtonItem` in a place that expects a view isn't going to work. Instead, you could just use `annotationThumbnail` like this:

```
annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = annotationThumbnail;
```

If you instead use a UIControl subclass, like UIButton, map's delegate will get a `-mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:` message if someone taps the callout accessory:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setBackgroundImage:someImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = someRect;
annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = button;
```

Comment: Sorry, button example isn't working. I also tried to change button type:        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);

Comment: @Flink Good call on the frame -- I should have set that. Please describe "isn't working." Crash? Compile error? Button doesn't appear? Don't get a message when you touch the button? I hope it's obvious that `someImage` should be a UIImage* that you've previously set to point to a valid image.

Comment: If I use UIButtonTypeRoundedRect than I see white rounded square, if I use UIButtonTypeCustom I see empty place instead. I tried different images. No crash a lot. Btw, thank you for your patience ;)

Comment: @Flink Sorry -- should have looked at the UIButton reference before posting. Try using -setBackgroundImage:forState: instead, as shown in the updated code above.

Comment: Thanks, that's worked :) Find also another way to solve it — using tapGestureRecognizer on image.